# How do you close the commit panel in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do you close the commit history (source code management) panel in VSCode? The left side of this image:

[image]

Without quitting the application or something else so drastic.

Comment: Can you right-click the pane or its header and choose "Auto hide" or "Close"?

Comment: The context menu on the left pane has some unrelated items (actions on the pane contents). And its header is noninteractive. However, after your comment I noticed you can also click the second part of the header on the *right* pane ("2 authors ...") to remove the left pane.

Comment: You had better post an answer with some screenshot for future readers to find the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are at least a couple different ways to close the commit history panel (here the left side):

1. With the Escape (esc) key, or
2. By clicking the second part of the header for the main (code editor) panel:

[image]